# Javascript collision global variable with local variable

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, global, local

**This is not my real code but it works for this issue:**

```
var string = 'Global';

function setStringToGlobal(string) {
  string = string;
}

function getStringFromGlobal() {
    console.log(string);
}

setStringToGlobal('haha');
getStringFromGlobal(); // In console log it says "Global", not "haha"
```

- First I try to set global "string" variable to "haha".
- Then I try to get it and print it out in the console log.
- It does not work because both global and local variable is called "string"

**Problem**

I like "string" both in my global and local scope. Is there a way I can still keep the names or do I have do rename one of them? If I need to rename, is there a good convention that is good here?

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/2ar2upqw/

Comment: Use capital letters for globally declared variables?

Comment: access global `string` using `window.string` syntax in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables should almost always be avoided because of name collisions just like this.

At the very least I would name space your globals onto the window object as Jaromanda mentioned. `window.string = string`

Because globals are normally avoided there is no established convention for their naming (that I am aware of). Using all caps `STRING` would normally be reserved for a constant.

---

On a side note:

This is probably more of an issue with approach. If you haven't already, I would look into the module pattern, which will assist you in managing scopes. https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

An alternative I have seen which leverages the module pattern:

```
(function (global) {
    global.string = 'Global';

    function setStringToGlobal(string) {
      global.string = string;
    }

    function getStringFromGlobal() {
      console.log(global.string);
    }

})(window);
```

Comment: Thanks! I already use the module pattern. My example was just... an example. My real code looks similar to the code posted here, except for the solution. I like to have module global variables because then I don't need to send them into every function in the chain.